# Разделение по столбцам характеристик, записанных в одной ячейке

Tags: excel, vba, excel-формулы

Есть список товаров, который нужно импортировать на сайт под управлением *CMS Bitrix* через *CSV*.  Столкнулся с такой проблемой: чтобы данные сопоставить с полями, данные необходимо сначала разделить.

В ячейке A1 хранятся все характеристики, их надо разнести по соответствующим столбцам (*С1 D1 E1 F1*...).

Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Товаров с такими характеристиками около 2к и порядок у некоторых отличается.

Comment: Действие 1 - разбить на 2 столбца по разделителю двоеточие. Действие 2 - транспонировать.

Comment: Вам нужно руками в Excel или программное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Инструмент *Разделить_по_столбцам* здесь не поможет: порядок характеристик может отличаться, названия характеристик останутся в данных.

*Подготовка*

На листе, куда предполагается выводить результат, создать таблицу, в названиях столбцов которой - названия характеристик.

Проверить разделители в исходных данных: между названием и характеристикой -  двоеточие; между характеристиками - перенос строки (символ 10)

**Вариант1. Обработка формулой**

Формулу записать на лист с новой таблицей в ячейку *A2* и копировать на нужный диапазон строк и столбцов:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(исходные!$A1;СИМВОЛ(10);ПОВТОР(" ";999));ПОИСК(A$1;ПОДСТАВИТЬ(исходные!$A1;СИМВОЛ(10);ПОВТОР(" ";999)))+ДЛСТР(A$1)+2;999))
```

здесь *исходные* - название листа с исходными данными, *A$1* - ссылка на шапку таблицы (название характеристики).

Если нужно обойти ошибки (например, нет данных в исходной ячейке, нет наименования характеристики), формулу можно "обнять" функцией:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(...);"а нетути!")
```

Для разнообразия еще одна формула:

```
=ЛЕВБ(ПСТР(исходные!$A1;ПОИСК(A$1;исходные!$A1)+ДЛСТР(A$1)+2;999);ПОИСК(СИМВОЛ(10);ПСТР(исходные!$A1;ПОИСК(A$1;исходные!$A1)+ДЛСТР(A$1)+2;999))-1)
```

**Вариант2. Обработка макросом**

Макрос разместить в общем модуле.

```
Sub SplitCharacteristics()
Dim aData(), aHead(), aRes(), aSpl
Dim sHeader As String
Dim lRw As Long, lClmn As Long
Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Long, p As Long, j As Long
    With wsCSV ' лист с объединенными данными'
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        aData = .Range("A1:A" & lRw).Value ' объединенные данные в массив'
    End With

    With wsRes ' лист для выгрузки результата'
        lClmn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        aHead = .Range("A1").Resize(1, lClmn).Value ' заголовки в массив'
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To lRw, 1 To lClmn) ' размерности массива для результата'

    For i = 1 To lRw
        If aData(i, 1) <> Empty Then
            aSpl = Split(aData(i, 1), Chr$(10)) ' разделяем характеристики, помещаем в массив'
            k = k + 1 ' строка в массиве результата'

            For p = 0 To UBound(aSpl) ' проходим по характеристикам'
                sHeader = Split(aSpl(p), ":")(0) ' заголовок характеристики'

                For j = 1 To lClmn ' проходим по заголовкам на листе'
                    If aHead(1, j) = sHeader Then ' заголовок совпал'
                        aRes(k, j) = Split(aSpl(p), ":")(1) ' записываем характеристику'
                        Exit For ' выходим из цикла к следующей характеристике'
                    End If
                Next j
            Next p
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsRes
        .Rows("2:" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2).Delete 'чистим лист от старых данных'
        .Range("A2").Resize(k, lClmn).Value = aRes ' выгружаем на лист новые данные'
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```

*wsCSV, wsRes* - внутренние названия листов, задать которые можно только в редакторе *VBA*. Если это сложно, вместо скрытых имен к листам можно обращаться по видимым именам:

```
Worksheets("исходные")
Worksheets("результат")
```

При желании можно почистить характеристики от единиц измерений, но это уже другая тема.

Пример обработки:

- исходные данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо больше разобрался,  но есть маленькая не точность , после запуска макроса ,  последняя характеристика не переноситься , в  результате  там пусто.  Например в у вас в примере в ячейке A1  есть длинна  - так вот в результате она будет пустой. А если после Длины добавить еще одну характеристику например ДИАМЕТР , то в результате   Длинна заполниться а ДИАМЕТР будет пустой

Comment: @Егор Ильин, точно: *For p = 0 To UBound(aSpl) - 1*  - так исключается из проверки последняя характеристика. Уменьшать на единицу не нужно. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое за труд , вчера разобрался сам

Answer (score 0):

1)Выделить столбец - Меню *Данные - Текст по столбцам: формат с разделителем - далее - символ двоеточие* - готово

2) Выделить столбцы - Копировать - *Специальная Вставка - Транспонировать*

Comment: При таком способе он возьмет только первую строчку

Comment: По сути надо сначала кажду характеристики раскинуть в ячейку а потом как нибудь расцеплять. Думал есть какой нибудь вариант по проще , чтоб не кодить не чего